# How to get node's close event to completely cancel get request?

Tags: node.js

Ok, so I found out there's a 'close' event on an ajax get request when user closes brower or goes to diff page, before the server had a chance to reply. But that close event doesn't stop things, it'll just send that event and will keep doing work inside the function even though user has closed the browser. What I'd like is for the whole doWork function to completely stop when user closes the browser. However, node just keeps on doing the work inside the function even when user isn't there anymore...

```
function doWork(req, res)
{
     req.on('close', function(err) {
        console.log("USER CLOSED BROWSER!!!");
        return; // but it doesn't really return....
     });

     // io process
     // cpu process
     // another io process
     // another cpu process
     // etc...

     res.json(newdata);


}
```

But how do I stop everything??? Would I do something like:

```
function doWork(req, res)
{
     var stopit = false;
     req.on('close', function(err) {
        stopit = true;
     });

     if (stopit) return;
     // io process

     if (stopit) return;
     // cpu process

     if (stopit) return;
     // another io process

     if (stopit) return;
     // another cpu process
     // etc...

     res.json(newdata);
}
```

i.e., before each new callback I should check if I should stop or not, but that seems a bit messy. isn't there a way to just stop EVERYTHING automatically?

Comment: It can't interrupt synchronous tasks once they've started as the event won't truly emit until the engine is free (with JavaScript execution occurring on just one thread). And, canceling asynchronous tasks depends on the individual task and related API; they may not offer the option to cancel.

Comment: No, all my tasks are asynchronous I didnt write the code exactly the way it is. I just want to know how to just stop all these tasks. Do I really need to do this manually is node that stupid?

Comment: No. There isn't a generic answer for what you want. Or, even a guarantee that an answer exists for each task. It all depends on the modules/packages you're using. You can prevent subsequent tasks from starting, but may not be able to cancel them once they've started.

Comment: It's reasons like these that I question if node even makes sense as a web server. I mean, a user disconnects and it keeps on going inside the get function? and there's no way to just tell it to stop, i.e just terminate this function? that's ridiculous.

Comment: In every threading environment I'm familiar with (Windows, Unix, VxWorks, etc) they all strongly recommend or require that threads cooperate in cancellation of work - it's just too unreliable to kill a thread. This is basically the same problem you have here with node, except the "thread" is implicit in the flow of async operations rather than with explicit threads.

Comment: "and there's no way to just tell it to stop, i.e just terminate this function? that's ridiculous." - First, there is a way, through programming. Secondly, this is how the vast majority of web app servers handle this at least to my knowledge, as in, they don't handle it. It's complicated to terminate a request after the fact and saves so few resources it is pretty rare that this is worthwhile to actually code.

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly code this in node, it is most certainly technically possible, but as your pseudocode indicates, it would be definitely not be automatic and somewhat intrusive and inelegant to code. Perhaps there's some elegant module on npm to help with this (probably using domains as the mechanism to track context), but if so I haven't seen it or any blogs or tweets about it. To my knowledge nobody ever does this. Node programmers work so their app can serve 1000s of requests per second. The benefit of aborting requests that have already been accepted and started processing is generally not very high, thus I have seen zero instances of anyone caring about this problem at all in production node apps. All the real handling of this case is taken care of by the OS's TCP stack via libuv, so it's "automatic" in that sense and in the sense that having additional processing after the request closes doesn't cause any runtime errors, but other than that node.js is general purpose enough to not have baked in the concept that all computing is done in response to a web request so there's no automatic way for node to know "oh this DB query is intended to provide data to respond to this particular web request, which has already closed, so let me just bypass that".